# Does Haskell have a splat operator like Python and Ruby?

Tags: haskell, tuples, splat

In Python and Ruby (and others as well, I'm sure). you can prefix an enumerable with `*` ("splat") to use it as an argument list. For instance, in Python:

```
>>> def foo(a,b): return a + b
>>> foo(1,2)
3
>>> tup = (1,2)
>>> foo(*tup)
3
```

Is there something similar in Haskell? I assume it wouldn't work on lists due to their arbitrary length, but I feel that with tuples it ought to work. Here's an example of what I'd like:

```
ghci> let f a b = a + b
ghci> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
ghci> f 1 2
3
ghci> let tuple = (1,2)
```

I'm looking for an operator (or function) that allows me to do:

```
ghci> f `op` tuple
3
```

I have seen `(<*>)` being called "splat", but it doesn't seem to be referring to the same thing as splat in other languages. I tried it anyway:

```
ghci> import Control.Applicative
ghci> f <*> tuple

<interactive>:1:7:
    Couldn't match expected type `b0 -> b0'
                with actual type `(Integer, Integer)'
    In the second argument of `(<*>)', namely `tuple'
    In the expression: f <*> tuple
    In an equation for `it': it = f <*> tuple
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can apply functions to tuples, using the [tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) package. Check out, in particular, the [uncurryN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Curry.html) function, which handles up to 32-tuples:

```
Prelude Data.Tuple.Curry> (+) `uncurryN` (1, 2)
3
```

Comment: I'm guessing this uses Template Haskell?

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat. Unfortunate that it looks to arbitrarily be defined only up to tuples of 15 elements, but that's probably plenty ;)

Comment: Yeah, it has to be defined for individual tuple types because in Haskell, each tuple type is technically a different type. (So `(a, b)`, or "pair", is a completely unrelated type to `(a, b, c)`, or "triple" -- they just have a special syntax that allows the construction of arbitrarily-large such types.) I don't think the above package is using Template Haskell, though I don't recognise the "|" symbol used in the class definition.

Comment: @mgiuca: The "|"-symbol in this context denotes a [Functional Dependency](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies).

Comment: @Chuck: There is no Template Haskell in the tuple package (though there is some custom Haskell code which emits other Haskell code as a String).

Answer (score 3):

The uncurry function turns a function on two arguments into a function on a tuple. Lists would not work in general because of their requirement for homogeneity.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying it can't be done on arbitrary-length tuples, but uncurry works for the special case of a pair?

Comment: @gfxmonk: Yes. Each combination of number and combination of types in a tuple is a distinct type in Haskell's type system, so a function can't take every tuple type.

Answer (score 3):

No, Haskell's type system doesn't like that. Check this similar question for more details:

[How do I define Lisp’s apply in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/why-is-such-a-function-definition-not-allowed-in-haskell)

BTW, the splat operator you talk about is also known as the `apply` function, commonly found on dynamical functional languages (like LISP and Javascript).

Comment: I believe this is correct for lists, but I asked specifically about tuples in the question.

Comment: @gfxmonk: Still, enumerables in Python are moe akin to lists, IMO, since they can be of arbritrary length and the splat works the same. In Haskell you can't have a function work on arbritrary tuples unless you use deep magic.