# Haskell Uncurrying for Multiple Arguments

Tags: haskell, currying

I have a Haskell data constructor that defines an "API" (in a higher layer in my app), so I don't want to change it:

```
ViewModel = ViewModel { foo :: Entity Foo
                      , bar :: Entity Bar
                      , baz :: Entity Baz
                      }
```

and I have a function that produces lists of triples:

```
getViewModels :: Monad m => m [(Entity Foo, Entity Bar, Entity Baz)]
```

Is there a general method to uncurry `ViewModel` in such a way that it consumes triples?  More generally, **is there a way to make `ViewModel` consume `n`-tuples?**

I have in mind something like this when I call my code:

```
do
  views <- getViewModels
  return . fmap (uncurryN ViewModel) $ views
```

where `N` is some natural number.

Comment: You can use template Haskell to generate an `uncurry` for every number (well up to the maximum number of elements a tuple can carry.

Comment: Though I have closed the question (and deleted my answer, for the sake of consistency -- it was the same as [the accepted one in the target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054444/2751851)), note that this a textbook example of an useful duplicate: essentially the same question, but phrased in a very different way.