# Haskell "Apply"?

Tags: haskell, types, lisp, polyvariadic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is such a function definition not allowed in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/why-is-such-a-function-definition-not-allowed-in-haskell)

I'm a newcomer to the world of Haskell, migrating over from Lisp. I'm trying to adjust to Haskell's fundamentally different worldview, and one of the many things that I find new and exciting is the type system. Being a Lisper, I thought I would try to implement in Haskell a function which is very important in the Lisp world: `apply`. For those who don't know, apply takes a function and a list of arguments, and invokes the function on those arguments. In Scheme, `(apply + '(1 2 3))` is the same as invoking `(+ 1 2 3)`, and returns 6.

My Haskell code looks something like this:

```
apply x [] = x
apply f (x:xs) = apply (f x) xs
```

But Haskell complains:

```
ERROR line 2 - Type error in function binding
*** Term           : apply
*** Type           : (b -> a) -> [b] -> a
*** Does not match : a -> [b] -> a
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

And I think that I understand why. Apply's type needs to be different depending on the length of the list it is given. Given a list of, say, 3 items, apply's type would need to be: `(a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b`, but given a list of 6 items, apply's type would need to be: `(a -> a -> a -> a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b`.

I tried this horrendous work-around:

```
data FnOrDat a b = Dat b | Fn (a -> FnOrDat a b)

apply :: (FnOrDat a b) -> [a] -> (FnOrDat a b)
apply x [] = x
apply (Fn f) (x:xs) = apply (f x) xs
apply (Dat _) _ = error "Cannot apply something which is not a function!"

add a = Fn (\b -> Dat (a + b))

main = putStrLn $ show $ x where Dat x = apply (Fn add) [5,1]
```

This works, but it hardly counts as an `apply` function, because I can't pass `apply` a normal function, I have to use one that has been written specifically to use my (awkward) FnOrDat abstraction. If I wanted to write a function that added four numbers, I would need to write

```
add4 a = Fn (\b -> Fn (\c -> Fn (\d -> Dat (a + b + c + d))))
```

Ew.

So - am I missing something, or is asking for a general-purpose `apply` basically like asking for a function that can manipulate an arbitrary-length tuple? Does `apply` even make sense in the statically-typed worldview of Haskell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`apply` isn't very useful in Haskell, since you can't give a type to the function.  As you see in your FnOrDat, you're essentially embedding a Lisp language into Haskell as an EDSL to force something through.

> asking for a general-purpose apply basically like asking for a function that can manipulate an arbitrary-length tuple?

Exactly. You can come up with type class instances for certain useful combinations of types, but there's just not really a need or use for a general variadic `apply`.

---

As a side note, you should consider upgrading to GHC and the [Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform), instead of the obsolete Hugs  system, since you're missing out on most of libraries, tools and language features developed in the last 10 years.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I do use GHC on my "main" computer. I'm typing this up somewhere else though, so I just used codepad.org to test my code snippets. I guess they use Hugs?

Comment: @Ord they do use hugs, with the `-98` flag. See http://codepad.org/about

Answer (score 4):

Notwithstanding Don's  explanation, `foldl1 (+)` would actually add all elements of a list. Hence, one could say that the `fold` family of functions comes quite close to the `apply` as the OP describes it.

Comment: Yes, for certain types of functions I guess. But if you had a function like `discriminant a b c = b*b - 4*a*c`, in Lisp you'd be able to say `(apply discriminant '(2 3 4))`. You can't do this with fold.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know why apply would ever be used like this. In Lisp, you usually use apply when you have a function that accepts any number of arguments, and this concept doesn't carry over to Haskell.

Comment: Well, yes, but then `apply3 f (a:b:c:_) = f a b c` is a one liner.

Comment: You can play games with currying though, to reflect arity into nested tuples, `uncurry ( uncurry discriminant ) ((2,3),4) ==> -23` . It's just not a Haskell thing to do.

Comment: @DonStewart Cool! I'd never heard of `uncurry` before. But yes, I see why it isn't really a common Haskell idiom.

Answer (score 1):

> ... a function which is very important in the Lisp world: **apply**. For those
>   who don't know, **apply takes a function and a list of arguments**, and
>   invokes the function on those arguments. In Scheme, **(apply + '(1 2 3))**
>   is the same as invoking **(+ 1 2 3)**, and returns **6**. ...

This is quite simple:

```
foldr  (+) 0 [1,2,3]
foldr1 (+)   [1,2,3]
```

results in 6.

To apply a function to each element of a list:

```
map f list
```

e.g.

```
map (2*) [1,2,3]
```

results in [2,4,6]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite. If you define `discriminant a b c = b*b - 4*a*c`, in Lisp you'd be able to say `(apply discriminant '(2 3 4))`. Another (more useful) example: in Lisp, the map function can take any number of list arguments. Not only can I say `(map square '(1 2 3 4)) -> '(1 4 9 16)`, but I can say `(map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) -> '(5 7 9)` (which is like zipWith), or `(map * '(1 2 3) '(3 2 1) '(0 2 0)) -> '(0 8 0)`. If I have a list of lists, x, I'd be able to say `(apply map + x)` to get the term-wise sum of the lists. You can't do any of these things with fold.