# What type signature do I need to allow a list of functions to be converted to haskell code?

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is such a function definition not allowed in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/why-is-such-a-function-definition-not-allowed-in-haskell)

I made a haskell function called `funlist`. What it does is it takes a starting value, and a list of functions, and applies all of the functions in the list to the starting value.

```
funlist thing [function] = function thing
funlist thing (function:functions) = funlist (function thing) functions
funlist _ _ = error "need a list of functions"
```

The problem with this function is that it has a type of `funlist :: t -> [t -> t] -> t`. That type means that while ghc will allow a list of functions that don't convert the starting value to a completely different type (e.g `[sin,cos,tan]` will be allowed), a function that converts the starting value to a different type (e.g `show`) will generate an error because that function doesn't match the type signature.

This isn't how the function should work. It should be able to take a list of functions that change the starting values type (e.g. `[sin,show]`). This function basically converts `funlist 5 [sin,cos,tan,isInfinite,show]` to `show $ isInfinite $ tan $ cos $ sin $ 5`, and while the latter works, the former doesn't.

Is there any way that I can get this function to work properly?

**EDIT:** I know about `.` and `>>>`, I'm just wondering if there's a way to make this work.

Comment: Does it work if you help the type system with `funlist :: a -> [a->b] -> b?`

Comment: Instead of building a list of functions why not build a function and use (.) the way you would use (:) in lists? If you need additional information like how many functions are already stacked, I would suggest using a state monad for this.

Comment: …if you help the typesystem with 'a -> [a->b] -> b', you can't chain the functions.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767407/ / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/

Comment: @sdcvvc : those are very similar, but are asking about lists of arguments instead of a list of functions.  On an abstract level they are similar but the answers are different.

Comment: @Christofian : Could you clarify what operations you need the "list of functions" to support?  Because (.) or (>>>) may be enough for your needs.

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz see my edited answer (I just want to see if there's a way to get this code to work)

Comment: There really isn't any way to do this that doesn't reduce to just composing them directly anyway...so you might as well just compose them anyway.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker was a moderator interference really necessary here, and if so, why not by someone who at least have a "haskell" tag showing among their 507 tags?

Answer (score 7):

You can write what  you want with a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Funlist where

data F x y where
  Id :: F a a
  Ap :: (a->b) -> F b c -> F a c

-- A very round about way to write f x = x + x

f1 :: Int -> Char
f1 = toEnum

f2 :: Char -> String
f2 x = x:x:[]

f3 :: String -> [Int]
f3 = map fromEnum

f4 :: [Int] -> Integer
f4 = foldr (+) 0 . map toInteger

f_list :: F Int Integer
f_list = Ap f1 (Ap f2 (Ap f3 (Ap f4 Id)))

ap :: F a b -> a -> b
ap Id x = x
ap (Ap f gs) x = ap gs (f x)
```

Now `ap f_list 65` is `130`

Comment: Note that `ap (Ap f gs) x = ap gs $! (f x)` would give you strict evaluation at the intermediate steps.  This may help for long function chains.

Comment: This is the (->) instance of the reflexive-transitive closure construction (Kleene star) mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777283/type-threaded-heterogenous-lists-and-defaulting-with-type-families/10777626#10777626

Comment: @Lambdageek : Almost another syntax for (>>>).  But it is possible to do "length" of the nested F's.  And possible to make a more elaborate GADT (e.g. add Typeable class constraint).

Comment: @pigworker : Yes, that `Star` GADT is a more abstract example of my `F`.

Answer (score 6):

This does not work with normal functions/normal lists in Haskell, since it requires a dynamically typed language, and not a statically typed language like Haskell. The `funlist` function can't have a different type depending on what the contents of the function list is at runtime; its type must be known at compile-time. Further, the compiler must be able to check that the function chain is valid, so that you can't use the list `[tan, show, sin]` for example.

There are two solutions to this problem.

You can either use [heterogenous lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList). These lists can store lists where each element is a different type. You can then check the constraint that each element must be a function and that one elements return type must be the next function's parameter type. This can become very difficult very quickly.

You can also use [`Data.Dynamic`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html) to let your functions take and return dynamic types. You have to perform some dynamic type casts in that case.

Answer (score 6):

If all you're going to do with this list of functions is apply them to a single value in a pipeline, then instead of writing and calling your `funlist` function, do this:

```
show . isInfinite . tan . cos . sin $ 5
```

or, if you don't want the list reversed in your code, do this:

```
import Control.Arrow (>>>)

(sin >>> cos >>> tan >>> isInfinite >>> show) 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew about these functions. I'm just trying to get the function I made to work.

Answer (score 4):

Functions in Haskell, in general, have types that look like `a -> b`, for some choice of `a` and `b`.  In your case, you have a list `[f0, ..., fn]` of functions, and you want to compute this:

```
funlist [f0, ..., fn] x == f0 (funlist [f1, ..., fn] x)
                        == f0 (f1 (funlist [f2, ..., fn] x))
                        ...
                        == f0 (f1 (... (fn x)))
```

The `t -> t` problem you're having is a consequence of these two things:

1. This computation requires the argument type of `f0` to be the return type of `f1`, the argument type of `f1` to be the return type of `f2`, and so on: `f0 :: y -> z, f1 :: x -> y, ..., fn :: a -> b`.
2. But you're putting all those functions in a list, and all the elements of a list in Haskell must have the same type.

These two, taken together, imply that the list of functions used in `funlist` must have type `[t -> t]`, because that's the only way both conditions can be met at the same time.

Other than that, dave4420's answer is the best simple answer, IMO: use function composition.  If you can't use it because the computation to be done is only known at runtime, then you want to have some data structure more complex than the list to represent the possible computations.  Chris Kuklewicz presents a very generic solution for that, but I'd normally do something custom-made for the specific problem area at hand.

Also good to know that your `funlist` can be written like this:

```
funlist :: a -> [a -> a] -> a
funlist x fs = foldr (.) id fs x
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, there's no way to do what you want with lists (in a sensible way, at least).

The reason is that lists in Haskell are always homogenous, i.e. each element of a list must have the same type. The functions you want to put to the list have types:

```
sin :: Floating a => a -> a
isInfinite :: Floating b => b -> Bool
show :: Show c => c -> String
```

So you can't just put the functions in the same list. Your two main options are to:

1. Use a structure other than list (e.g. HList or a custom GADT)
2. Use dynamic typing

Since the other answers already gave GADT examples, here's how you could implement your function using dynamic types:

```
import Data.Dynamic

funlist :: Dynamic -> [Dynamic] -> Dynamic
funlist thing (function:functions) = funlist (dynApp function thing) functions
funlist thing [] = thing
```

However, using dynamic types causes some boilerplate, because you have to convert between static and dynamic types. So, to call the function, you'd need to write

```
funlist (toDyn 5) [toDyn sin, toDyn cos, toDyn tan, toDyn isInfinite, toDyn show]
```

And unfortunately, even that is not enough. The next problem is that dynamic values must have [homomorphic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism) types, so for example instead of the function `show :: Show a => a -> String` you need to manually specify e.g. the concrete type `show :: Bool -> String`, so the above becomes:

```
funlist (toDyn (5::Double)) [toDyn sin, toDyn cos, toDyn tan, toDyn isInfinite,
    toDyn (show :: Bool -> String)]
```

What's more, the result of the function is another dynamic value, so we need to convert it back to a static value if we want to use it in regular functions.

```
fromDyn (funlist (toDyn (5::Double)) [toDyn sin, toDyn cos, toDyn tan,
    toDyn isInfinite, toDyn (show :: Bool -> String)]) ""
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want works in Haskell, but it's not a list.  It is a function composition and can actually be wrapped in a GADT:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

data Chain :: * -> * -> * where
    Chain :: (a -> c) -> Chain c b -> Chain a b
    Id    :: Chain a a

apply :: Chain a b -> a -> b
apply (Chain f k) x = apply k (f x)
apply Id x          = x
```

Now you can inspect the structure of the function chain to some extent.  There isn't much you can find out, but you can add further meta information to the `Chain` constructor, if you need more.

The type also forms an interesting category that preserves the additional information:

```
instance Category Chain where
    id = Id

    Id . c           = c
    c  . Id          = c
    c2 . Chain f1 k1 = Chain f1 (c2 . k1)

instance Arrow Chain where
    arr f = Chain f Id

    first (Chain f c) = Chain (first f) (first c)
    first Id = Id
```

Answer (score 0):

There where some answers using GADTs, which is a good way to do such things. What I want to add here is that the structure used in these answers already exists in a more general fashion: it's called a [thrist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/thrist/0.2.2/doc/html/Data-Thrist.html) ("type threaded list"):

```
Prelude Data.Thrist> let fs = Cons (show :: Char -> String) (Cons length Nil)
Prelude Data.Thrist> let f = foldl1Thrist (flip (.))  fs
Prelude Data.Thrist> :t fs
fs :: Thrist (->) Char Int
Prelude Data.Thrist> :t f
f :: Char -> Int
Prelude Data.Thrist> f 'a'
3
```

Of course, you could also use `foldl1Thrist (>>>) fs` instead. Note that thrists form a category, an arrow and a monoid (with `appendThrist`).