# Haskell pass contents of list as arguments

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is such a function definition not allowed in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/why-is-such-a-function-definition-not-allowed-in-haskell)

Good day!

I'm trying to write/to find a function g that translate a list of arbitrary finite size to function arguments, such as

```
    g k [a,b,c,d] = k a b c d
    g f [a,b,c] = f a b c = ((((f) $ a) $ b) $ c)
```

Syntactically that seems like `g = foldl ($) f`, but the compiler reasonably fails to apply that function, answering:

```
     ghci> let (><) f = foldl ($) f
     <interactive>:1:19:
     Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b = b1 -> b
     Probable cause: `$' is applied to too many arguments
     In the first argument of `foldl', namely `($)'
     In the expression: foldl ($) f
```

So I fail to produce some working implementation. Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try starting by writing down a type signature for `g` first, then figuring out how to implement it. ;]

Comment: I tried that at first, but I cannot define it `g :: f->[a]->b :: (a->a->...->b)->[a]->b`. I don't know the `f` type in advance.

Comment: See that as a hint. Haskell is statically typed, so if you could implement it, you could also write down its type.

Comment: It is the same question indeed! Many thanks, I didn't find it by myself. Migrating there...

Comment: Little wonder, since the other question has an *atrocious* title. I should probably fix that...