# Partially apply function n times

Tags: haskell

Assume

```
f x y z = x*y*z
```

Then I expect to return the application of f three times with each member of the list

```
foldl ($) f [1,2,3]
```

Something like `(((f 1) 2) 3) = 1*2*3 = 6`

The function `f` would be the accumulator and each iteration of the fold would apply one argument and return a partially applied function as the next accumulator.

Why doesn't this work? Is it because `f` changes type while iterating?

As an aside: is there any other way to accomplish this type of function application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I define Lisp’s apply in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168880/how-do-i-define-lisp-s-apply-in-haskell)

Comment: As a really trivial counterexample, consider `foldl ($) f [1,2,3,4]`. It's clearly wrong, so if you want `foldl ($) f [1,2,3]` to typecheck and `foldl ($) f [1,2,3,4]` to not then you need to find some way to distinguish `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]` in types. This doesn't happen with plain lists, and [once you do this you can write the function you desire.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector)

Comment: I believe this question is much more specific than the general Lisp apply.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to know (a) why `foldl ($) f [1,2,3]` doesn't typecheck in Haskell as it stands, (b) can Haskell be changed to make it type-check, (c) what different expression can be written in current Haskell instead that would type-check or (d) something else ?

Comment: As for Scheme's `apply`, I have heard Scheme experts complain bitterly about its existence. It apparently makes good compilation rather more difficult. Scheme long ago gutted its `eval` for this same reason, and I think the implementors would probably love to nix `apply` altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types look like

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a

($) :: (x -> y) -> x -> y
```

To apply `foldl` to `($)` requires matching (technically, unifying) the type of the first argument to `foldl` with the type of `($)`. That is, solving the equation

```
a -> b -> a  =  (x -> y) -> x -> y
```

This leads immediately to

```
a = x -> y
b = x
a = y
```

Substituting the second and third equations into the first:

```
a = b -> a
```

The problem is that Haskell *has no type* that solves this equation. In particular, it is impossible to write down a solution with a finite number of symbols! It expands first to

```
a = b -> b -> a
```

then

```
a = b -> b -> b -> a
```

and on forever. So there is *no way* to choose types for the type variables to make them match, and GHC will complain loudly.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't do what you're trying to do because the type system distinguishes between functions with different numbers of arguments. What you're trying to do, essentially, is convert a list of values into a list of arguments for a function, which doesn't make sense in context.

However, the instance you're pointing at is literally just `foldl (*)`. If you're performing the *same* operation on all of the variables in a function, you can just use this (well, you should be using either `foldl'` or `foldr`, but you get the idea).