# Foldln in haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Is it possible to write in haskell something similar to fold functions on many lists. Here is example for such function in Racket

```
#lang racket
(define (fold-left f i as . bss)
  (if (or (null? as)
          (ormap null? bss))
      i
      (apply fold-left
             f
             (apply f i (car as) (map car bss))
             (cdr as)
             (map cdr bss))))
 
(fold-left + 0 (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7 8))
(fold-left + 0 (list 1 2 3) (list 2 3 4) (list 3 4 5) (list 4 5 6))
(fold-left (λ (i v n s) (string-append i (vector-ref v n) s))
           ""
           (list (vector "A cat" "A dog" "A mouse")
                 (vector "tuna" "steak" "cheese"))
           (list 0 2)
           (list " does not eat " "."))
```

The example uses of fold-left evaluate to 36, 42, and "A cat does not eat cheese.".
It seems to me not yet, but perhaps there is some trick that I haven’t thought of?

Comment: So what does this do? Arbitrary recursion?

Comment: `foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b` exists. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Yes, arbitrary recursion until end of some list. In racket var args are passed to the function via list. So bss is a list of lists. car and cdr return head and tail respectively.

Comment: @DanielWagner no. Your function accepts only 1 argument (excluding
 accumulator), while my accepts arbitary number of arguments

Comment: @ostalyi `foldl'` accepts a `Tree`, which may have an arbitrary number of children. It is merely a different syntax -- `f [a,b,c]` instead of `f a b c`. (Well, okay, that's a `Forest`, not a `Tree`. But it's trivial to adapt -- just nest your folds.) But, if you must have function application syntax, then [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6168880/791604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *direct* equivalent because that would require creating list with (dynamically) heterogenous types. However, you can still pretty much achieve the same result using other operations in Haskell:

```
(fold-left + 0 (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7 8))
```

Would be `sum $ zipWith (+) [1,2,3,4] [5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
(fold-left (λ (i v n s) (string-append i (vector-ref v n) s))
           ""
           (list (vector "A cat" "A dog" "A mouse")
                 (vector "tuna" "steak" "cheese"))
           (list 0 2)
           (list " does not eat " "."))
```

Would be

```
concat $ zipWith3 (\v n s -> concat [v!!n, s])
  [ ["A cat", "A dog", "A mouse"]
  , ["tuna", "steak","cheese"]
  ]
  [0, 2]
  [" does not eat ", "."]
```

`zipWith3` can be extended to any arbitrary (but fixed, because static typing) number of lists with the `Applicative` instance of `ZipList`:

```
zipWith<n> f l1 ... ln === f <$> ZipList l1 <*> ... <*> ZipList ln
```

So basically, instead of stuffing everything inside one big fold that somehow 'knows' how deep to go, you'd just write out the folds explicitly.

Comment: The main stumbling block is the ability to accept a fold function of arbitrary arity, and to use the function's type to determine how many list arguments to accept. I know `Text.printf` does some type-class magic to make the return type depend on the string argument; I don't know if there's something similar you could do with the fold function.